# How to filter objects from consumption.usage_details.list()?

Tags: python, azure, sdk, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to filter in only those objects which fall under a given date criteria. But I am unable to do so!

```
consumption = ConsumptionManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id, base_url=None)
for obj in list(consumption.usage_details.list(filter=date_filter))
print(obj.usage_start)
```

I have tried:

```
date_filter = 'usage_start ge 2019-02-11T23:59:59Z'  
date_filter = 'properties/usage_start ge 2019-02-11T23:59:59Z'       
date_filter = 'usageStart ge 2019-02-11T23:59:59Z'    
date_filter = 'properties/usageStart ge 2019-02-11T23:59:59Z'    
date_filter = 'properties/UsageStart ge 2019-02-11T23:59:59Z'    
date_filter = 'UsageStart ge 2019-02-11'    
date_filter = 'usage_start ge 2019-02-11'    
date_filter = 'properties/usage_start ge 2019-02-11'    
date_filter = 'usageStart ge 2019-02-11'   
date_filter = 'properties/usageStart ge 2019-02-11'    
date_filter = 'properties/UsageStart ge 2019-02-11'    
date_filter = 'UsageStart ge 2019-02-11'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the test method for usage_details.list() in [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure-mgmt-consumption/tests/test_mgmt_consumption.py). You can take a try follow that article.

date definition:

[image]

then apply filter like this: `date_filter ='usageEnd le '+ str(endDate)`

[image]

Hope it helps.